# Move files in client machine

Tags: client-server

We have a OPENGL application.We deployed that in the server.While running from the client machine,errors are coming up saying it requires some .dll files when they have already been bundled in the jar.We are trying to create a temporary folder in the c drive of the client machine and download the .dll files as well as a batch file in it.Using the DOS prompt of the client machine we are running the batch file.It copies the .dll files in the bin folder of the jre.How can we set permissions to do this operation in the client machine?

Comment: This question is very vague and poorly defined. Please improve it.